# Realm Unable to find any way to Delete Nest Object Or Inner Object

Tags: java, android, realm

I am using realm in my application because of it is easy to use, but for many days I am stuck with a Problem.

Actually I want to delete an object which is using in two different classes. The problem is when I delete the object with code of

```
realm.delete(Trip.class);
```

This will delete my Trip Object from another class where it is using.

For more clarication let me share with you my pojo classes

```
public class ListsAndTrips extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

@PrimaryKey
String primaryKey = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;
@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private GetList list;
@SerializedName("save_type")
@Expose
private String save_type;
@SerializedName("trip")
@Expose
private Trip trip;
private final static long serialVersionUID = -5166224864956253999L;
```

This is my ListAndTrip class which using Trip and GetList Object

```
public class TripsList extends RealmObject implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("type")
@Expose
private String type;

@SerializedName("list")
@Expose
private GetList list;

@SerializedName("trip")
@Expose
private Trip trip;
```

This is my TripsList calss which also using Trip and GetList class.
Now the problem is if I delete from TripsList Class the Trip of GetList object will also deleted from ListsAndTrip class

Is there any way to delete the object with relation of parent class

How I am deteling?

```
                                    realm.delete(ListsAndTrips.class);
                                    realm.delete(Trip.class);
                                    realm.delete(GetList.class);
```

Comment: You should tag your question with your coding language.

Comment: @Jay I Just Edit it